# How can I sove this using mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables as under.

```
worker
-----------------------
ID  NAME
1   James
2   Robert
3   David
4   Peter

task
-----------------------
ID  Title
1   Painting
2   Repairing
3   Wiring

assoc
------------------------
worker_id   task_id
2       1
1       2
1       1
```

On painting page, I want to display all worker name but with yes / no against painting.

I want

```
-------------------------
Worker  Can Paint
----------- ---------------
James   Yes
Robert  No
David   Yes
Peter   No
```

How to write SQL statement? I have no good effort to show. Please help.

Comment: That's great! All you have to do now is to write an SQL query. Good luck!

Comment: Don't just ask for code. Tell us what you have tried. Do some work yourself.

Comment: Try http://www.google.com.

Comment: Thanks The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: user986959 I am here after enough googling only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select w.name, case when sum(t.id is not null) > 0 
                    then 'yes' 
                    else 'no' 
               end as paint
from worker w
left join assoc a on a.worker_id = w.id
left join task t on a.task_id = t.id and t.title = 'Painting'
group by w.name
```

Comment: +1 : `jeft join`?  I know a guy called `Jeft`, but he's not a joiner :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, 
CASE a.task_id
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
   WHEN NULL THEN 'No'
END
FROM worker w
LEFT JOIN assoc a ON
w.ID=a.worker_id AND a.task_id=1;
```